# Anylogic is assigning the value to all entities instead of only one

Tags: anylogic, model-based-testing

My source has the following code in "On at exit" field: 
TRUCK.ID_number = parameter;
parameter = parameter + 1;

Then, each truck will receive an ID: 1, 2, 3, ...

The problem is that All the trucks are circulating at the same time and it looks like everytime a new truck is generated and the code runs it resets the ID for all trucks.

For example: When truck 4 (ID = 4) is created at the source all the other trucks receive ID 4 so I cannot know the correct ID of each truck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you holding your `parameter` field and what type is it? If it's an `Integer`, rather than an `int`, you will get the symptoms you mentioned because `ID_number` is then an object reference. If something like this is the case, I can explain more in an answer...

Comment: parameter is being held in Main window, type "int". 

I am really lost here. It should be something very simple... Record IDs and other characteristics of each entity during the process then collect the information in the end (sink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a few things. First, you need to use the keyword `agent` in the onExit code box. So in your case, `agent.ID_number=parameter`. Please read up on these specific keywords that pop up everywhere in AnyLogic code boxes. I call it the "magic lightbulb", also see my blog on that topic:

[The magic lightbulb](http://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling)

Second, newly created agents automatically get a unique index (if they belong to the same population). You can access that using the `getIndex()` method inside your truck agent.

Comment: Thank you! But I still think I am doing something wrong here. 

When I add the code you said I get error messages.

agent.ID_number=parameter ===> agent cannot be resolved to a variable

Agent.ID_number=parameter ===> ID_number cannot be resolver or is not a field

Entity.ID_number=parameter ===> Entity cannot be resolved to a variable

entity.ID_number=parameter ===> ID_number cannot be resolver or is not a field

Comment: you need to use lower case "agent", not "Agent". You really need to read up on these key words and on Java programming in general. It is very case sensitive. Also, make sure you typed it into a code box that actually supports the keyword "agent" (read my blog on how to do that). hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

The answer is: Use **entity.ID_number=parameter**

Comment: Leo, it is "entity" in AnyLogic 6 (and the deprecated enterprise library in AnyLogic 7). However, it is "agent" in AnyLogic 7. Please specify which version you use if you use older versions of a software. cheers